# Free fall for a longer time

Tags: newtonian-gravity, free-fall, equivalence-principle

When I'm in free fall, I'm weightlessness for only about 1-2 seconds. Is there any way I can feel weightlessness for a longer period of time?

Comment: [Here's one way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_gravity_aircraft)

Comment: Errr..  Fall further!

Comment: The cheapest way is to jump from a building, but unfortunately, most people don't survive the collision at the bottom. Next cheapest (and survivable) would be sky jumping.

Comment: @LDC3: Neither of these will give you reasonable weightlessness for much longer than two seconds because aerodynamic drag starts giving you proper acceleration quite quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Establish a longer free fall time, for example in an [aircraft](http://www.gozerog.com/) or [space station](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station).

Answer (score 0):

There are private space companies that will allow you to take a trip to space(it costs around $250,000). Take a trip and go in orbit around the earth or go to another space station. Another solution would be to go to the Zero-G place as Lasse said or fall farther as Rob Jeffries said which are both much less expensive.